# Controlling the Color property of a bootstrap dropdown list element when containing GridMvc is Selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that is using bootstrap. Usually I customise scaffolded views.
For example, the Index view of a model is usually a table with rows of the records
of that model in the database plus links to "Edit", "Delete" each record plus a link to the "Details" of that model. Sometimes I add more links and collect them
in a Bootstrap dropdown menu.
Recently I started using the NuGet package GridMvc to make some of the models'
index views paged, sortable and filterable.

[image]

However, I have now run into a problem. When I click on the button labelled "Actions", the color property of the row changes to white in order to make the text visible inside the now highlighted row. But the background-color of the
dropdown list only changes on hover, thus making the text invisible if the cursor is not hovering over it.

[image]

I notice that when a GridMvc row is clicked on, some jQuery code is called
and then the color properties of the row change. But I am wondering if there
is a way to control the new color values when the properties change. It'd be
really nice to be able to use both GridMvc (as it makes implementing paging, sorting and filtering easier) while still maintaining the bootstrap dropdown
menu button (as it makes the UI a lot cleaner) and not have to sacrifice one
for the other.

I would appreciate any suggestions or recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the browser tools, I discovered this piece of code,
that comes with the Grid.Mvc CSS, was responsible for styling the links in the dropdown menu.

```
table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a {
    color: white;
}
```

So all I did was to override it with my own CSS rule

```
table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a {
    color: black;
}
```

And the result was this:

[image]

I also had to add this rule:

```
table.grid-table tr.grid-row-selected a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

To change the color property of the link text to white on hover
because white text on blue background looks better than black text on
blue background.